# pandas dataframe filter rows by values of column that is a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe:

```
df = col1. col2. col3
      1.    2.   []
      3.    1.   [A]
      8.    9.   [C,D]
      2.    4.   [E]
      9.    2.   [E,T]
```

I want to take only rows when E not in col3 and A not in col3
So in the example, I will have:

```
      1.    2.   []
      8.    9.   [C,D]
```

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: @jezrael typo pls see edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If need remove all rows if not `A` or not `E` in lists use [`set.isdisjoint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set.isdisjoint) with [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df = df[df.col3.map(set(['A','E']).isdisjoint)]
print (df)
   col1  col2    col3
0   1.0   2.0      []
2   8.0   9.0  [C, D]
```

Another idea is convert lists to `DataFrame`, so possible use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html):

```
df = df[~pd.DataFrame(df.col3.tolist(), index=df.index).isin(['A','E']).any(axis=1)]
print (df)
   col1  col2    col3
0   1.0   2.0      []
2   8.0   9.0  [C, D]
```

If need test only `E`:

```
df = df[~df.col3.map(lambda x: 'E' in x)]
print (df)
   col1  col2    col3
0   1.0   2.0      []
1   3.0   1.0     [A]
2   8.0   9.0  [C, D]
```